# MYSQL - How to group by and take the value that is not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name  | Color | Fruit | Animal
-----------------------------
Steve | Blue  | Null  | Null
Steve | Null  | Apple | Null
Steve | Null  | Null  | Sheep
John  | Red   | Apple | Null
John  | Null  | Null  | Cow
```

ETC...

I want it to condense into

```
Name  | Color | Fruit | Animal
------------------------------
Steve | Blue  | Apple | Sheep
John  | Red   | Apple | Cow
```

Other group by solutions I've tried don't really work well with Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use max and group by

```
SELECT t.name,
       max(t.color) as color,
       max(t.fruit) as fruit,
       max(t.animal) as animal)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY t.name
```